# If K and H are normal subgroups of $G$, $H \cap K = \{1\}$ and both $G/H$ and $G/K$ are abelian, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be a group, and $H \trianglelefteq G$, $K \trianglelefteq G$.

Prove that if $H \cap K = \{1\}$ and $ G / H $ and $ G/ K $ are abelian, then G is abelian.

I've tried to give a proof by contradiction but couldn't really get anywhere. If $ ab \ne ba $ then $\pi_{H}(ab) = \pi_{H}(ba)$ and I get a similar result with $\pi_{K}$ but can't really get much from that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The obvious homomorphism $\phi: G\to G/H\times G/K$ is injective, since the kernel is the set of elements in $H\cap K$. Since both quotients are abelian, the product is abelian, and $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the product, and is thus abelian itself.

Comment: Love this one, beautiful proof. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let $a, b \in G$.  Consider $[a, b]:=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ which is frequently called the commutator. (Up to choice of convention.)

Then the hypotheses tell us that $[a, b] \in H$ and $[a, b] \in K$ because $ab=ba$ mod $H$ or $K$.

Comment: I seem to have forgotten that aS = bS iff b^(-1)a is in S. Thanks, very nice proof.